# Replacing several winforms controls with custom controls in VS2010

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have inherited a VB.net project, and I need to give several ListBoxes some custom functionality. So I've created a subclass of System.Windows.Forms.ListBox, and now I'd like to replace several "regular" ListBoxes with my subclass.

I want to be extremely careful not to change any properties that are set in the designer, so I'm hoping to just "drop in" my replacement.

Does the VS2010 winforms designer have a built-in way of simply changing the user control's type, without deleting and re-inserting the control?

Comment: You're probably best off opening the .designer.vb file and doing a text replace on " System.Windows.Forms.ListBox".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to change the type in the Form.designer.vb file.  Every control used on the form is declared in there.

Comment: I've tried that before in other projects, but it left me a little uncomfortable because of the message in there that says `Do not modify it using the code editor`. Is there any chance that the change would be overridden by Visual Studio, or that there could be other unforseen issues with doing that?

Comment: No, it will not override the change in type.  I've done it countless times myself with no ill effect!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it will be best to use the Visual Studio find and replace tool to replace the ListBox control where you need to in all the .ASPX files as well as the .designer.cs files.

You'll need to add a reference to your control's assembly in the .ASPX files too.

Comment: where can one find this tool in VS 2015 ?